# Playing custom notification sound

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am using the following code to play a custom notification sound.

```
public class PlayNotification {

private Context context = null;

public PlayNotification() {}

public PlayNotification(Context context)
{
    this.context = context;
}

public void play(String soundClipID)
{


    try {


        Uri ringToneUri = PhoneUtils.getNotificationSoundUri(context, soundClipID);
        Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, ringToneUri);
        r.play();

      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Currently, when I get a notification from that app, it plays the expected sound *along with the default notification sound set on the phone.*

How to prevent the default notification sound from playing? I know I can set the sound as default itself, but I do not want to alter system defaults, as this notification sound is to be played under specific circumstances only.

Comment: Where is the notification created? You can set a flag so that it doesn't play any sounds.

Comment: When any app gives a notification, it will trigger a notification sound based on the default set by user. I want to disable that while my custom notification sound plays. Right now, both are playing. Here I am trying to play a custom notification sound when a notification arrives, and I am not trying to create a custom notification.

Comment: Correct, but where does the notification come from? If you do not control the source then I'm afraid you probably can't disable the sound.

Comment: Yes that's what I inferred as well. Luckily I found a work-around. By setting my notification stream volume to 0 for the duration for which my custom sound plays (my custom sound plays on a separate stream, like ALARM stream) I got the functionality I was after. Since the duration for which the sound plays is very short, this is OK I feel, but nevertheless its a crude hack. Hoping for a better solution here :)